# Dice roll game win probability

Tags: python, logic

I am trying to code a dice game where the user can bet e.g. one to three dollars. It then rolls a fair, `x`-sided dice (I was thinking `x==6`). If the user wins, their money is doubled (e.g. if they bet three dollars and win, they get six dollars).

I was wondering if there are any sites that state what the win chance should be so the dice remains fair, yet the house, in the long run, always wins? I remember in my logic classes there being a sort of formula. Something along the lines of: `chance_of_winning * price`.

Comment: Either the dice rolls fair, or the house wins. These are mutually exclusive requirements.

Comment: You are right. What should the win chance of a user be in order for the house to always win (in the long run) while giving the user a chance of winning.

Comment: Why don't you look up the rules to an existing casino-based dice game (e.g. craps)?

Comment: If the gambler must bet on a single value, and the house wins on any other value, then in a large number of rolls, the house will win `5/6` of the time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am looking for a formula of sorts. i have other games I want to code so my goal is to have a formula that will determine who wins in the long run.

Comment: This appears to be a question about probability, rather than programming, but note that you basically need to set it so that the probability of winning is slightly less than the odds offered on doing so.

Comment: @CoryKramer we could do it that way, or I was thinking, if the roll is 1~2, then the user wins. If the role is 3~6, then the house wins. The question is, are these win chances good enough to where in the long run, the player will lose. Rememeber, whenever the player wins they double their initial investment (1~3 dollars)

Comment: @Jorge what do you mean *"remember"*? That's new information. If the odds are 2:1 but the probability of winning is 1 in 3, of course the house wins. If you search for *"Monte Carlo simulation"*, that's exactly the sort of thing you can use here.

Comment: @Jorge Again this is trivial, if the gambler gets `1-2` and the house gets `3-6`, then the house wins `2/3` of the time

Comment: May be mathematics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just find the expected value of ```1-2``` and ```3-6```using the formula which you had in your question. ```(1/3)*6- (2/3)*3  = 2 -  2 = 0```, in other words the gambler will break even eventually. So for the house to come out on top you will need to change the odds more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should keep the probability at 1/x as this will keep it as a fair dice but make the return larger then x eg x +1 so the expectance is x+1/x for example which means that they will gain money